AWS Cognito Federated sigin-in is not including custom scopes
I am trying to use Cognito Federated Signin with Google so that my app can invoke GMail APIs. However, the oauth2/authorize endpoint of Cognito is not including the custom scopes that I have created through resource server in the query parameters of the redirect URL that I have included in my Cognito App Client.
https://abcapp.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/&response_type=code&client_id=347kv9biok10rkc24t5nsshg9t&identity_provider=Google&scope=email openid profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

is redirecting to:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=533651921202-fjilk90h8n4ok4p6o01eibepv.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://abcapp.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse&scope=profile email openid&response_type=code

without including the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly custom scope.
But I am sure the Hosted UI configuration shows the custom scope:

